# React-chart.js 2 Error in modules but was already installed in the package.json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I have already installed react chart js 2 but it still have this kind of error

> ./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.modern.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js'

This is my package.json file
[image]

BarChart.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const state = {
  labels: ["Nausea", "Fever", "Muscle Pain"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "1st Dose",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [65, 59, 80],
    },
    {
      label: "2st Dose",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [30, 20, 10],
    },
  ],
};

export default class Barchart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Bar
          data={state}
          options={{
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Average ",
              fontSize: 20,
            },
            legend: {
              display: true,
              position: "right",
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the Homepage:

import BarChart from "../../Components/Charts/BarChart";

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BarChart />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Could you post the full error message here, please?

Comment: I've edited it already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need chart.js as well as react-chartjs-2.

`npm install chart.js`

Comment: I'm still seeing this if anybody runs across a solution please post an update.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow these steps to resolve your problem :

- Delete the 'node_modules' folder from your project and package-lock.json
- npm install
- If issue still persists then run
- npm i react-chartjs-2 or npm i chart.js
- Or Remove react-chartjs-2 from package.json
- npm i react-chartjs-2 or npm i chart.js

Comment: You say to run `npm i react-chartjs-2 or npm i chart.js` - how do you suggest I determine which of the two options to run?  I tried your suggestin of deleting node_modules and running npm install again, but this problem persists - and I don't know which of your two suggestions to try from the 4th bullet point